# Regex: match pattern but not certain word

Tags: regex

Is there a possibility to write a regex that matches for `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` but not for the word `test`? Or do i need to filter this in several steps?

Comment: A tip: always specify which language and regex engine you're using; they're often different.

Comment: if you plan to replace every 2-4 character word in a string, you should mention that too, because depending on the solution parts of "test" could match too. but then there are other solutions more helpful

Comment: no its just for matching a string like this: `foobar.aaa.dsf` but there are strings like `foobar.test.dsf` i dont want to match. so its not about replacing something or so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?!test)[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

I don't know if you'll need it for what you're doing, but note that you may need to use start and end anchors (`^` and `$`) if you're checking that an entire input matches that pattern. Otherwise, it could match something like `ouaeghAEtest` because it will still find four chars somewhere that aren't "test".

Comment: Also, for multiple word exclusions: `(?![test1,test2])[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`

Comment: @shrx Not quite. You've used a character class, so the lookahead will only match against the first character if it is one of those listed. ([diagram](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LyIpMYTAhJ9Gja4x)) So it will reject any word that begins with a `t`, `e`, `s`, `1`, `,`, or `2`. Use the pipe "or" operator instead: `(?!test|foo|bar)[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` ([diagram](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Y3oVV178HTqb6LRw))

Answer (score -1):

```
[A-Za-su-z][A-Za-df-z]{0,1}[A-Za-rt-z]{0,1}[A-Za-su-z]{0,1}
```

just a idea, haven't use real code to try